# How to cross ref's from dictionaries & lists

Tags: list, dictionary

I am new to the whole python thing. I have a question and will try to keep it short.
I am trying to write a program where I have a group of items as below.

```
product_lookup = {"C1557E" : "FM51", "C1557E" : "JBC4343" "C1565ECA/2" : "FM349", 
           "C1568E" : "FM133", "C1578E" : "FM154"}
```

Now I have a enquiry (list of values) as below that I want to cross referance with the dictionary

```
enquiry_lookup = ["FM51", "FM133", "FM154", "GRE4534"]
```

Then I" want this displayed as

```
result ["FM51" : "C1557E", "FM133" : "C1568E", "FM154" : "C1578E", "GRE4534" : "NOT AVAILABLE"]
```

Firstly, is it possible?

I am stick... HELP PLEASE :)
Only just started and after working on a few things I am getting the feeling it might not be possible??
Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks a stack

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you a clue:

```
>>> dict = {"a" : "b", "c" : "d"}
>>>
>>> for k,v in dict.iteritems():
...     print k
...     print v
...
a
b
c
d
```

By using iteritems(), we iterate over all key,value pairs in our dictionary. So you can inspect the value to see if it is the value you are looking for, if so you can place the key and the value in your result dictionary.

But, if you are interested in a set of items, and those items are the values instead of the keys of your dictionary, are you sure your dictionary is not backwards? By which I mean, could your dictionary instead be

`product_lookup = {"FM51" : "C1557E", etc}`

then when you have

`enquiry_lookup = ["FM51", etc`

you can just see if product_lookup["FM51"] exists? This could be more efficient/easier to write.